# Python copy files from computer in active directory

Tags: python, active-directory

I have created a virtual environment using HyperV that includes a WinSrv2016 and two W10 Pc. Remote desktop connection is working fine from server to clients.

Using python I want to be able to connect from my server to my client pc's, using their credentials (ip, username, password) and copy specific files (ex. from their desktop).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.